# Error in tf.contrib.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am running the following code in tf_1.2:

```
inp = tf.contrib.keras.layers.Input(shape=(height, width, depth)) 
conv_1 = tf.contrib.keras.layers.Convolution2D(conv_depth,(kernel_size, kernel_size), 
    padding='same', 
    kernel_initializer='he_uniform', 
    kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001), 
    activation='relu')(inp)
 model = tf.contrib.keras.models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=conv_1)
 a = tf.contrib.keras.layers.Input(shape=(height, width, depth))
 enc_a = model(a)
```

And getting the following error

```
tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/engine/topology.pyc in run_internal_graph(self, inputs, masks)
1955           # Keep track of unconditional losses
1956           # (e.g. weight regularizers).
-> 1957           self.add_loss(layer.get_losses_for(None), None)
tensorflow/python/layers/base.pyc in add_loss(self, losses, inputs)
254     if not losses:
255       return
--> 256     self._losses += losses
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_losses'
```

The same code works if I remove  kernel_regularizer, and it also works if I am importing keras not tf.contrib.keras

Comment: Which version of Keras do you have installed? as far as I know, tf.contrib.keras is updated less regularly than Keras itself, is it possible this is a difference caused by a recent update of Keras?

Comment: 2.0.4 but I think its not a version problem.

Comment: [This is the Tensorflow implementation of Container](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/engine/topology.py) which is subclassed by Model, and [this is the Keras 2.0.4 implementation of the same class](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/2.0.4/keras/engine/topology.py). As you can see they are indeed different, so it des look like a version problem to me. (where by "version" I also mean the difference between tf-implemented and "official" Keras implementation

Comment: Ok. I thought that because its a generic code versioning of keras should not make a difference; but its true that tf.contrib.keras may not have all "features"

Comment: I think this question would fit better as an issue in the Keras github, at it looks like a bug in the implementation of the kernel_regularizer in tf.contrib.keras